# What tools can resize the partition where Windows7 resides?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows

On my laptop, I have Windows 7 installed on `/windows-c`, and my partitions `/` and `/windows-d` are running low. How can I arrange more space for these two partitions from `/windows-c`?

Gparted output:

[image: gparted output]

System monitor output:

Note: `/windows-c` and `/windows-d` are ntfs. What does system monitor mean by `fuseblk`?

[image: system monitor file systems tab]

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of `Gparted`. It would give better understanding of arrangement of your partitions.

Comment: yes, done. @g_p

Comment: Do you want to free space space from `/dev/sda2`.

Comment: I want to use some free space of `/dev/sda2` to add to `/dev/sda7` i.e. `/` and /dev/sda3` i.e. `/windows-d`.

Comment: guy, I think you need a bigger disk...

Comment: @gio900: If I buy a bigger disk, can I copy the installed Windows and Ubuntu  to that bigger disk, and still have both OSes work without installation again? (I don't want to buy Windows7)

Comment: @Tim Yes, and there are many instructions for migrating data to new hard drive online.

Comment: @Xieerqi: could you point me to some good ones/

Comment: @Tim I haven't done migration personally ( that's what I plan in future when I save up some $ for new 1 TB drive ), but here's one article from life hacker:" http://lifehacker.com/5517688/how-to-upgrade-your-tiny-hard-drive-to-a-spacious-new-one-and-keep-your-data-intact   " They mention clonezilla - a tool specifically for cloning hard-drive data. There's also Linux's dd command, but I can't give that 100% approval myself, because, again, haven't played with it much

Comment: You only have 6GB free on your Windows partition.  That's essentially a full disk.   Try looking for files in Downloads or temporary files that you can delete.  Maybe move some stuff to a USB flash drive.   With so little space, Windows probably doesn't have enough room to defragment C:\ which means it'll get slower and slower as it writes files in tiny chunks.

Answer (score 1):

As far as partition resizing goes, GParted is already a good tool for that. I've got Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop, and used GParted to resize both partitions. If you look at the GParted screen-shot, the key icon tells you those partitions are locked. You're aware of that right ? Boot of an Ubuntu live usb, unmount the hard-drive, and open GParted. Unlock the partitions, and resize them as desired. Also, good idea is to free-up space by deleting stuff you don't need, or move it to optical disks/USB sticks/cloud storage.

More info :http://www.howtogeek.com/114503/how-to-resize-your-ubuntu-partitions/

Comment: are you sure that win7 will allow less than 70Gb to it's OS?

Comment: There are folks who make minimal installation of windows under 50 - GB, but I can't say anything about already installed Windows with 100% certainty. I gave my Ubuntu partition like 18GB at first, then resized it to 41 GB, and the rest has been left for Windows. But windows partitions is pretty filled up, I think I only have 40 GB left there. And it works on my laptop, so . . .I guess the answer is yes (?)

Comment: I think yes, too. But use a SO in a partition filled more than now (and now it's filled 90%), doesn't look like a good idea to me. :)

Comment: Welp, there's always USB sticks,cloud storage and optical drives, right ? But the final judgement is up to the owner of the hard-drive

Answer (score 1):

First of all it may cause a boot failure. If it happens, you will needed to repair it using [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

As you want to free some space from `/dev/sda2/` and want to add it to  `/dev/sda`7 and your Ubuntu partition.

- Boot into the live mode using Ubuntu CD or USB.
- OPen Gparted Partition Editor.
- Now right click on `/dev/sda2` and select resize. Make some free space in the left side of `/dev/sda2`
- Now right click on `/dev/sda3`, select resize and drag the box according to your need. Leave some space in the left side of `/dev/sda3`, which you will add to your `/` i.e `/dev/sda7`.

*Note one thing that you have made some space free in your primary partitition, which you want to add in your extended partition i.e `/dev/sda7` (`/`).*

- So drag the box of your extended partition, and take the free space(after `/dev/sda3`) inside it.
- Once free space is inside extended partition box, repeat the above procedure to add it to add this free space to your `/dev/sda7`
- Once you are setishfied with your partition scheme, apply it.